# Admin page inaccessible after installing WebForm extension

Tags: php, magento

I have recently installed a free version of the WebForm extension (Community Edition) and immediately after the installation was complete I could no longer access the backend here `galawatch.com/admin`.

However, my store seems to be working fine.

I now want to uninstall this free version and purchase the paid one, can you please advice on what I need to do. First to completely uninstall the Free WebForm from my server. As I am very much new to Magento, I would appreciate it if you could help me out with this.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated in installation process. You'll need to remove all files from *app/code/community/VladimirPopov/WebForms/* and the .xml file(s) which shipped with the extension from *app/etc/modules/*, likely *VladimirPopov_WebForms.xml*

You should check if there is a *sql* amd/or *data* folder under the extension directory to see if there are any schema changes to undo as well.

You can test potential effects by editing the file under *app/etc/modules/* so that its `<active>` flag is false. Clear the cache and recompile if necessary to preview the effects.